# TMaskEdit, запись текста

Tags: delphi

Пытаюсь записать текст в `MaskEdit`, но почему-то не записывается. Хотя в другой форме делал то же самое и все работало.

Маска:

```
!9\ --\ 9;0;0
```

Обработка

```
if Length(mePriceFormat.Text) = 0 then
  mePriceFormat.Text := '00'
else if Length(mePriceFormat.Text) = 1 then
  mePriceFormat.Text := '0' + mePriceFormat.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае необходимо учитывать следующее:

1. Длинна текста в MaskEdit может быть по условиям маски 0 (когда ничего не введено); 1 ( когда введен один символ); 2 (когда введено 2 символа). Добавьте обработку для случая когда Length  = 2 что бы обслуживались три варианта. или сделайте блок Case для этих случаев.